# How can i change the path of pid file in MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

I have the MySQL 5.6 installed on CentOS6.4.

I read this

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-default-changes.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-default-configuration-file.html

i have the `my.cnf` in `/usr/my.cnf` folder.

Currently the pid file is being written in `/tmp` folder because i got error few hours back

now i have two questions

1. How to find where is MySQL writing the its data pid file
2. How to chnage it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1) To find out wehere mysql stores its pid file use the following:

```
mysql> show variables like '%pid%';
+---------------+-------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                         |
+---------------+-------------------------------+
| pid_file      | /var/lib/mysql/your-db.pid    |
+---------------+-------------------------------+
```

2) You can change this either by setting in in the my.cnf, here the option would look like the following `pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/your-db.pid`. Or you can change it by altering startup parameters and append `--pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/your-db.pid`. I would strongly suggest that you stick to the my.cnf option, the other solution would require some fiddling in your start-scripts.

3) You find the documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_pid-file

I just wanted to add that you can put the pid file wherever it suits you best, this means you don´t need to put it in your datadir or mysql-home. But a "clean" way to do so is under `/var/run/` under linux.

Comment: how can i define what error file to use

Comment: Hi, There is a subtlety here. Mysql documentation said that pid-file variable in my.cnf config file set the pid file location BUT it's not taken in consideration during startup process if variable is set in command line. See bug report [Bug #84172](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=84172).

Answer (score 3):

you can change the pid file in my.cnf it self. Mostly my.cnf will be available in /etc/my.cnf. you can edit the path of pid file. please find the below entry as an example...

datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/mysqld.pid

Comment: where is this in mysql documentation for 5.6 , i cant find it there